# Use link to open source Google Chrome Developer Tools Sources tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

When running JS unit tests in Google Chrome, occasionally tests fail with a stack trace. The test infrastructure knows the file that failed and possibly the line that caused the failure. I'd like to be able to view the failing .js file in the 'Sources' tab of the Google Closure Developer Tools via a clicking a link.

Is it possible to craft a link such that, if the dev tools window is already open that:

1. the dev tools window gets focus
2. Sources tab is selected
3. file in question is open

The more I think about it, this sounds like maybe a chrome extension would be required?

Answer (score 0):

I agree you would probably need a plugin. You can however create a view-source link (though no line numbers):

```
<a href="view-source:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660106">view source</a>
```